# jquery через on не видит данные загруженные через ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Добрый день, загружаю форму через ajax, навешиваю к примеру 
на input id='test'

```
$('#test').on('click', function(){
alert('Тест');
});
```

но событие не срабатывает, в консоли ошибок нет.

Не могу понять почему так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что когда выполняется

```
$('#test').on('click', ...
```

элемента c `id="test"` еще нет в дереве страницы, и выборка `$('#test')` - пустая. Вам надо использовать делегирование:

```
$(document).on('click', '#test', function...
```

где обработчик навешивается на что-то определенно существующее, а элемент с `id="test"` может появиться внутри этого существующего позднее.

Comment: блин,точно.... спасибо!